# LAMP in Ubuntu instance - OpenStack

Tags: 12.04, lamp, cloud, openstack

I have installed `OpenStack` using `DevStack` on a single machine and I have to develop a **Private Cloud Document Management System** and I just *want to provide storage of documents on the cloud*, nothing else.

My question is that Would I have to launch a **Ubuntu** instance and deploy my website pages in that instance using `LAMP`?

And how will I be able to store my documents in **Swift**? Or I can store on `OpenStack` host?

Answer (score 0):

1st Deploy an instance.
2nd Install LAMP.
Devstack or Openstack has a RESTful Web Service Endpoint to Handle all of its Features and Here is the Reference: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-objectstorage-v1.html

This reference is for creating containers, managing accounts, and creating objects, then you can use your application to upload the data to these objects and containers.

If you will be using this for public application, then you will put security into consideration.